# jetty run-war: restarting the server returns 404

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I have a maven application and configured the `pom.xml` to run the mvn jetty. Everythig starts up without errors, but I am always getting 404, and WEB-INF is always empty.

I did  `mvn clean install` and then `mvn jetty:run-war`.

On restarting the server I always get the 404.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the path that you are hitting.  For example, if your app is named sample-app, depending on your maven config you may need to hit http://localhost:8080/sample-app-SNAPSHOT.0.1 or whatever.  The port, the path, all are configurable.

Make sure you are getting the 404 from the right server.

Otherwise, would need to see the pom.xml to be sure.